# Mongodb Object id displaying weiredly

Tags: mongodb

I have Database in which there are few collections. 
In one collection the _id field is displaying as

```
"_id" : ObjectId("58b0196947c4f14490d18741")
```

While other collection is Displaying something like this

```
 "_id" : {
                "timestamp" : 1487170280,
                "machineIdentifier" : 8083947,
                "processIdentifier" : 12168,
                "counter" : 5289607,
                "time" : NumberLong("1487170280000"),
                "date" : NumberLong("1487170280000"),
                "timeSecond" : 1487070280
        }
```

Not sure what is root cause for it.

Comment: Bad code is the cause of course. I'd be looking at the codebase to see what is writing to this collection. Bottom line is that something is saving a serialization of it's own internal formal into the `_id` field rather than using an `ObjectId` type. But not really a question someone can usefully answer here without seeing the offending code.

Comment: Look @ your code where you Insert (or insertOne) Somewhere in there is a mixup as you probably are defining the _id instead of allowing Mongodb to insert it on its own. Somewhere in there definitions are being added to that field with key => values. That would be the source of the problem.